# How do I fix the error "attempt to select more than one element in integerOneIndex"?

Tags: r, na, recode

I'm debugging a function that rotates through a series of groups in an input file, fixing any within group problems. In this snippet, I am only interested in fixing a specific factor level within a factor variable. Note that, for these subsets, the values in `Sex`, `UsualResidents`, and `StatusID` are the same. In the larger data frame, these differ as these variables are the group definitions.

I've encountered the error:

```
Error in x[[jj]] <- v : 
attempt to select more than one element in integerOneIndex
```

on the 44th time it's been used. I have narrowed down the problem to this line, where the `stfixval` is passed into the function as a string. In this case, the string is `Partnered`. I have done this snippet so that hopefully it passes as it does in the function, I've checked in the function and `cls(stfixval)` is a character.

```
stfixval <- "Partnered" 

ProblemData[is.na(ProblemData$StatusID)] <- stfixval
```

This code snippet is adding in the factor label (level?) for any missing levels, due as a result of an earlier join. The fix has worked for any of the 43 previous subsets that had a factor level of `NA`. I found this solution earlier on this site to replace a missing factor value, and it's worked for prior groups with an `NA` value for this variable

In case there is something weird about this subset, rather than typing it into here, I have created a public repo on GitHub ([rds file here](https://github.com/programgirl/public/blob/main/ProblemData.rds)) so you can get the actual data - it's a very small file, only 10 rows and 8 columns.

If it was failing on other groups I would understand the problem. But I can't work out why it fails on this one. I tested in the console, too, and I get the same error trying to work on that subset data frame directly.

Why is it failing on this subset and what do I need to change to fix the problem?

Update, the `dput()`

```
 structure(list(SingleAge = c(30, 34, 25, 32, 29, 33, 31, 28, 
 26, 27), Sex = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
 "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), UsualResidents = structure(c(6L, 
 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("One Usual Resident", 
 "Two Usual Residents", "Three Usual Residents", "Four Usual Residents", 
 "Five Usual Residents", "Six Usual Residents", "Seven Usual Residents", 
 "Eight or More Usual Residents"), class = "factor"), Fits = c(0.825802885298389, 
 0.907626463702454, 0.563424742306557, 0.879067146224702, 0.788922087592366, 
 0.896242467639439, 0.855717792665186, 0.744666248145727, 0.632348764077823, 
 0.692617400687639), TotalinStatus = c(4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L), StatusID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("Partnered", "Non-partnered", "Not Elsewhere Included"
), class = "factor"), NuminDesStatus = c(2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 
 2, 2, 0), ExpectedCount = c(3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I linked to the file in my GitHub repo.

Comment: Data should be included in the question and not linked externally (links break over time). If it's a small data set, you should easily be able to include a `dput()` of your data in the body of your question.

Comment: I don't know if the problem is something corrupted in the file. It has worked 43 times previously.

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of one column of the data.frame? Perhaps you mean `ProblemData$StatusID[is.na(ProblemData$StatusID)] <- stfixval` or `ProblemData[is.na(ProblemData$StatusID), "StatusID] <-  stfixval`. Or is `ProblemData` a data.table rather than a `data.frame`? The indexing just doesn't look right so I can't see how it would have worked for any input.

Comment: It's a data frame. And just the one column. The problem is that the variable is a factor with 3 levels, only one of which is being used here. So it has to take the underlying factor number as well as the label thing.

Comment: `df$StatusID[is.na(df$StatusID)] <- stfixval` works

Comment: Thanks, both. I now wonder why it worked the other times. I had an error on an earlier subgroup and implemented that as the solution - and it worked, no NA in that column. That's why I was stuck on how it failed this other time.

Comment: Working perfectly, including for the earlier groups, now to debug the next problem! Thanks!